# Specifying unsigned char storage for integer numerals

Tags: c++, literals

In terms of modern C++, is it possible to specify storage of a integer numeral to a char?

I am looking to write `auto var = 255;` to initialize var as *unsigned char* type

It is possible to specify other types of storage:

```
auto var_ulong = 255ul;
auto var_float = 255.f;
```

However, not short or char? Surely I am missing something...

Comment: If you know what type you want, you could just declare that type.

Comment: `255` is an integer expression, so it will be an `int` if you use `auto`.

Comment: [I don't think you are missing anything](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal). You could cast, but that kind of defeats the point of using `auto`. Perhaps a user-define literal will work. Just checked. It works, but it's just a glorified cast.

Comment: there weren't any suffixes for short or char because everything will be promoted to int in an expression, hence those suffixes would be useless

Comment: @phuclv It would work to initialize a variable like OP wants to do it though. `consteval unsigned char operator"" _uchar(unsigned long long x) { return static_cast<unsigned char>(x); }` and then `auto var_uchar = 255_uchar;` would make `var_uchar` an `unsigned char`.

Comment: "*I am looking to write `auto var = 255;` to initialize var as unsigned char type*" You mean besides writing `char var = 255;`? Are you in a template deduction context and you need to ensure that the type is deduced as `char`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo:

constexpr unsigned char operator"" _uc(unsigned long long x)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(x);
};

not const eval. that fixes my issue! now I can just auto all my var definitions MAGIC! 5*!!! :D

Comment: @BebeCarabina `consteval` is new in C++20. `constexpr` is the next best for this.

Comment: My simple test looked like `constexpr uint8_t operator"" _uc ( unsigned long long int n ) { return static_cast<uint8_t>(n); }` and worked in C++ 17. That said, this is a case where I'd just avoid `auto` . When I can afford any surprises, I don't use `auto`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard integer literal to do what you want, but you can add your own [*user- defined literal*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) if you plan to do this a lot:

```
namespace foo {

// constexpr pre C++20
//  |
//  V 
consteval unsigned char operator"" _uchar(unsigned long long x) {
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(x);
}

}
```

```
using namespace foo;
auto var_uchar = 255_uchar;
```

Just be aware that normal integer promotion will still be in effect, so below, you'll get an `int`:

```
auto var_int = 55_uchar + 10_uchar;
```

Comment: it's still longer than `uint8_t var = 255` though

Comment: @phuclv `uint8_t` is an optional type. It doesn't even need to exist. Also, the `_uchar` part is _user-defined_. You can make it `consteval unsigned char operator""_C(unsigned long long x);` (with no space between "" and _C) if you want it as short as possible.

Comment: I know about user-defined literals but `short x = 1` and `char x = 1` are still shorter than `auto x = 1_s` and `auto x = 1_c`

Comment: @phuclv I don't get what your point is. I was answering OP:s request "_I am looking to write `auto var = 255;` to initialize `var` as `unsigned char` type ... It is possible to specify other types of storage: `auto var_float = 255.f;`_" with that there is no such literal for `unsigned char` but that it's possible to make a user-defined literal and gave an example for the specific type OP asked about. Where does the length of it come into the question? That's not what OP asked for and I think I have answered OP:s question. Don't you?